# Use of indexes in tensor calculus

Tags: real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

I'm reading Carlo Rovelli's "General relativity" and I'm sometimes puzzled about the way he uses indexes (I haven't studied tensors in a formal way, just googled something). For instance, one exercise asked to determine what happens when we change variables in a frame field: suppose we have a surface with some general coordinates $x^a=(x^{1},x^2)$ and we want to move to the coordinates $y^a=(y^1,y^2)$. Then Rovelli claimes that the new frame field is $E_{a}^{j}=\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial y^a}e_b^j$, where $e$ represents the former frame field. I don't understand where does the $b$ index come frome, could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Obviously I do understand the way the chain rule is applied, I'm just puzzled about the index

Comment: If $A,B$ are matrices, and $(A)_{ij}, (B)_{ij}$ denote their elements (row $i,$ column $j$), do you understand where $k$ comes from in $(AB)_{ij} = \sum_k (A)_{ik}B_{kj}$?

Comment: In broad strokes it's a "dummy index" used to express the Leibniz formalism$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y_a}=\sum_b\frac{\partial x_b}{\partial y_a}\,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_b}.$$